# how to insert data inside an array from each loop in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

From last 5 hours i am trying to solve out one single thing and think almost made it but stuck somewhere due to which not getting the result i want. I think here i need a bit expert level help to rectify where i am doing wrong.

```
var eduarray = [];
$('.education-groupbox').each(function(index, el) {
    eduarray[index] = [];   
    var s = $(this).attr('id');
    //console.log();
    $('#'+s+' .inputs').each(function(key, value) {

        //eduarray['index'].push("rohit");

    });

});
```

What i am trying to get is the result in format of object with multiple array from the each each loop so that i can send the data through formdata and process the php form.

```
 <div id="education-groupboxwrapper">
                    <div id="education-groupbox" class="education-groupbox">
                      <div class="inputs col-3">
                        <label for="email">Bölüm</label>
                        <input type="text" name="email" />
                      </div>
                      <div class="inputs col-3">
                        <label for="email">Okul Adı</label>
                        <input type="text" name="email" />
                      </div>
                      <div class="inputs col-3">
                        <label for="email">Bölüm</label>
                        <input type="text" name="email" />
                      </div>
                      <div class="inputs col-3">
                        <label for="email">Bölüm</label>
                        <input type="text" name="email" />
                      </div>
                    </div> 
                  </div>
```

Comment: why is `inputs` with `s`, in `$('#'+s+' inputs')` ? also please consider posting a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with minimum required code within the question, i.e your HTML structure

Comment: Post HTML part too.

Comment: Give an example how you want it

Comment: sorry for the html part missed .. i have added it now .. you may also visit here and check the current running form http://rohitchoudhary.in/caliphp/register_account

Comment: Why re-invent the wheel? Just use [`serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) on the form itself

Comment: ´.inputs´ not ´inputs´. You dont have <inputs> tags

Comment: can you show me a demo about serialize() .. i will also try at my end once in this way . Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: There is example in the docs I linked to and many tutorials online

Comment: inputs is a class name

Comment: You also can't repeat `name` values without using array notation. Study some form tutorials

Comment: if it's a classname then you should write **`.inputs`** with a **dot**

Comment: that was not a working code i am working on it just try to get the data first

Comment: Initially your data set will be empty. When do you want to capture input's value?

Comment: Mi-Creativity :) thanks buddy by correcting this single basic mistake i can now get value in the second loop :) thanks alot.. i will try now and test if i can get the result .

Comment: can anyone please guide me how do i insert value to my array in my second loop please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code you I found some bug, `$('#'+s+' inputs').each` won't work since ID are unique, use class instead so you can have multiple inputs under same input group with the same class name.

Use `eduarray[index].push($(this).val());` to push value into array.

`$('.education-groupbox').each` will loop though each block of HTML for `<div class="education-groupbox">` therefore inside the each using `$(this).find('input')` will return all input inside this block, then you can use each to push all input value to the array.

```js
var eduarray = [];
$('.education-groupbox').each(function(index, el) {
  var _this = $(this);
  eduarray[index] = [];
  _this.find('input').each(function(key, v) {
    eduarray[index].push(v.value);
  });

});

console.log('eduarray[0] -->' + eduarray[0]);
console.log('eduarray[1] -->' + eduarray[1]);
console.log('eduarray    -->' + eduarray);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="education-groupboxwrapper">
  <!-- groupbox 1 -->
  <div class="education-groupbox">
    <div class="inputs col-3">
      <label for="email">Bölüm</label>
      <input type="text" name="email" value="test1" />
    </div>
    <div class="inputs col-3">
      <label for="email">Okul Adı</label>
      <input type="text" name="email" value="test2" />
    </div>
    <div class="inputs col-3">
      <label for="email">Bölüm</label>
      <input type="text" name="email" value="test3" />
    </div>
    <div class="inputs col-3">
      <label for="email">Bölüm</label>
      <input type="text" name="email" value="test4" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- groupbox 2 -->
  <div class="education-groupbox">
    <div class="inputs col-3">
      <label for="email">Bölüm</label>
      <input type="text" name="email" value="test111" />
    </div>
    <div class="inputs col-3">
      <label for="email">Okul Adı</label>
      <input type="text" name="email" value="test222" />
    </div>
    <div class="inputs col-3">
      <label for="email">Bölüm</label>
      <input type="text" name="email" value="test333" />
    </div>
    <div class="inputs col-3">
      <label for="email">Bölüm</label>
      <input type="text" name="email" value="test444" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for the brief Daniel . I hope this helps let me try once Thanks

Comment: thanks for the updated code. but i am getting Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (register_jobseeker.js:159)

Comment: @RohitPoonia `_this.find('input').each(function(key, v) {
    eduarray[index].push(v.value);
  });`

Comment: hey i got it eduarray[index].push there is a mistake i did in here and you saved my day man. Thanks a lot

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144733/discussion-between-rohit-poonia-and-daniel-h).

Answer (score 2):

This is how you do it:

```js
$(function() {
  $('button').on('click', function() {
    var eduarray = {};
    $('.education-groupbox').each(function(index, el) {
        var s = $(this).attr('id');
        eduarray[s] = [];   
        $(this).find('input').each(function(key, value) {
          eduarray[s].push( $(this).val() );
        })
    });

    console.log(eduarray);
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="education-groupboxwrapper">
  <div id="education-groupbox" class="education-groupbox">
    <div class="inputs col-3">
      <label for="email">Bölüm</label>
      <input type="text" name="email" />
    </div>
    <div class="inputs col-3">
      <label for="email">Okul Adı</label>
      <input type="text" name="email" />
    </div>
    <div class="inputs col-3">
      <label for="email">Bölüm</label>
      <input type="text" name="email" />
    </div>
    <div class="inputs col-3">
      <label for="email">Bölüm</label>
      <input type="text" name="email" />
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>

<button>SAVE</button>
```

I created an object (rather than array), and iterate over `'.education-groupbox'`. For each element I created a new array inside that object, based on the element's ID. Next, on each element in the loop, I selected all the inputs (`$(this).find('input')`), and pushed them to the array.

You can also save the label of each input (If you need it) like this:

```js
$(function() {
  $('button').on('click', function() {
    var eduarray = {};
    $('.education-groupbox').each(function(index, el) {
        var s = $(this).attr('id');
        eduarray[s] = {};   
        $(this).find('.inputs').each(function(key, value) {
          var $el = $(this),
              label = $el.children('label').html()
          if( 'undefined' === typeof eduarray[s][ label ] ) { eduarray[s][ label ] = []; }
          eduarray[s][ label ].push( $el.children('input').val() );
        })
    });

    console.log(eduarray);
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="education-groupboxwrapper">
  <div id="education-groupbox" class="education-groupbox">
    <div class="inputs col-3">
      <label for="email">Bölüm</label>
      <input type="text" name="email" />
    </div>
    <div class="inputs col-3">
      <label for="email">Okul Adı</label>
      <input type="text" name="email" />
    </div>
    <div class="inputs col-3">
      <label for="email">Bölüm</label>
      <input type="text" name="email" />
    </div>
    <div class="inputs col-3">
      <label for="email">Bölüm</label>
      <input type="text" name="email" />
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>

<button>SAVE</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not forget that the classes in jQuery are with a `.[myClass]`

```js
$(function () {
  var eduarray = [];
  function submit() {
    $('.education-groupbox').each(function (index, el) {
      eduarray[index] = [];
      var s = $(this).attr('id');
      $('#' + s + ' .inputs').each(function (key, value) {
        //You have to do it like the previous one but here if you add the data
        eduarray[index][key] = $(value).find("input").val();
      });
    });
  }
  //Then you call the function only when you send
  $("button").click(function () {
    submit();
    console.log(eduarray);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="education-groupboxwrapper"><div id="education-groupbox1" class="education-groupbox"><div class="inputs col-3"><label for="email">Bölüm</label><input type="text" name="email" /></div><div class="inputs col-3"><label for="email">Okul Adı</label><input type="text" name="email" /></div><div class="inputs col-3"><label for="email">Bölüm</label><input type="text" name="email" /></div><div class="inputs col-3"><label for="email">Bölüm</label><input type="text" name="email" /></div></div><div id="education-groupbox2" class="education-groupbox"><div class="inputs col-3"><label for="email">Bölüm</label><input type="text" name="email" /></div><div class="inputs col-3"><label for="email">Okul Adı</label><input type="text" name="email" /></div><div class="inputs col-3"><label for="email">Bölüm</label><input type="text" name="email" /></div><div class="inputs col-3"><label for="email">Bölüm</label><input type="text" name="email" /></div></div></div>

<button>submit</button>
```

Comment: hey avril . what if i have a select box in place of input in just two inputs class like this:

<div class="education-groupbox">
    <div class="inputs col-3">
      <label for="email">Okul Adı</label>
      <select name="">
       <option>Name</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="inputs col-3">
      <label for="email">Bölüm</label>
      <input type="text" name="email" value="test3" />
    </div>
      </div>

Comment: how do i get the value from both different fields

Comment: @RohitPoonia put: `if($(value).find("input").length){/*input tag*/}else{/*option tag*/}`

Answer (score 0):

You can try with below way.I have pre populated the html value to get scenario work. Please change accordingly.
JS

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
          var eduarray = [];
        $('.education-groupbox').each(function(index, el) {
        eduarray[index] = [];   
        var s = $(this).attr('id');
        console.log(s);
        $('#'+s+' input[type=text]').each(function(key, html) {
            eduarray[index].push(html.value); 

        });

        });
        console.log(eduarray)
        })
    </script>
```

HTML

```
<div id="education-groupboxwrapper">
                    <div id="education-groupbox" class="education-groupbox">
                      <div class="inputs col-3">
                        <label for="email">Bölüm</label>
                        <input type="text" name="email" value="123" />
                      </div>
                      <div class="inputs col-3">
                        <label for="email">Okul Adı</label>
                        <input type="text" name="email" value="456" />
                      </div>
                      <div class="inputs col-3">
                        <label for="email">Bölüm</label>
                        <input type="text" name="email" value="789"/>
                      </div>
                      <div class="inputs col-3">
                        <label for="email">Bölüm</label>
                        <input type="text" name="email" value="abc" />
                      </div>
                    </div> 
                  </div>
```

Answer (score -2):

Hope it will work

```
var eduarray = {};
$('.education-groupbox').each(function(index, el) {
    eduarray.index = [];   
    var s = $(this).attr('id');

    $('#'+s+' input').each(function(key, value) {
        eduarray['index'].push("your value");
    });
});
```

Comment: *"Hope it will work"* doesn't explain anything that you did differently. Not to mention that `inputs` is an invalid selector